I can't seem to make a filtered word list match when trying to put it before the list
Maybe i'm overlooking something but in this regex (rust)
testword./[\d\w\W]*(?:text|moretext|[\p{Emoji}--\p{Digit}^*#])
it gets caught when both words after testword./ are present at any position like this: testword./text .
However putting it this way text testword./ does not catch whatsoever.
I tried to fix it by doing (?:text|moretext|[\p{Emoji}--\p{Digit}^*#])[\d\w\W]*testword./ (testword is simply on the other side of the regex) which did the trick but putting both testwords together like this testword./[\d\w\W]*(?:text|moretext|[\p{Emoji}--\p{Digit}^*#])[\d\w\W]*testword./ does nothing. Essentially i'm trying to catch text and moretext before and after the occurrence of testword./. Yes, i know there are backreferences and look-aheads and similar or even this
testword./[\d\w\W]*(?:text|moretext|[\p{Emoji}--\p{Digit}^*#])|(?:text|moretext|[\p{Emoji}--\p{Digit}^*#])[\d\w\W]*testword./

but this is not ideal as it's for discords Automod which its regex is limited to 260 characters and sadly 'fancy-regex' is not supported meaning no backrefs and look-arounds and similar.

I suggest you begin by stating your problem without reference to a regex. That will help readers understand the problem with your regex and possibly also allow them to offer broader suggestions for solving your problem. It would also be helpful if you would give a least one example string, showing both the desired result and the result you are getting with your regex.

The example string is the combined one, the testword./........testword./. It is supposed to catch text and moretext while testword./ is present but it does not catch instead the results are none. Here's a regex101 if that helps: result1 and result2 i'm getting and desired result.

r"[\w\W]" is saying "match anything that is a word character or not a word character". In other words, match anything. Might as well just use a dot ([\d\w\W]* is same as .*). Make sure you make it a raw string, or properly escape your backslashes. And consider non-greedy matches when using "*" or "+" (*? is non-greedy).
